# Which gnuplot terminal type should I use in org-babel-gnuplot with latex export

Tags: latex, gnuplot, org-mode

All gnuplot examples on http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-gnuplot.html use the png terminal.  However, when exporting to latex I'd rather like to generate vector graphics.  Latex terminal seems to be outdated.  Eps does not work as a result of how orgmode invokes pdflatex.  So which terminal type can I use with org-babel-gnuplot and latex export?

As an alternative question: How can I make org-mode call pdflatex so that it uses the eps graphics?

Comment: You could let gnuplot output data as a table and format it with LaTeX, e.g. with pgfplots.

Comment: @N.N. how would you do that in org-mode?

Comment: @aristoex I dunno how org-mode works. In a normal LaTeX document you can use something like `\draw plot[domain=0:5] function{x**2};` within a `tikzpicture` to draw a part of the function x².

Comment: @artistoex you should be able to start the bounty now with higher rep to give away

Comment: Without knowing anything about your software, do these articles help : [Include EPS graphics in pdflatex](http://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/eps-and-pdflatex-no-more-converting-eps-to-pdf/) and [org-exp-blocks.el — pre-process blocks when exporting org files](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-exp-blocks.html) ?

Comment: Let me know how useful they were.

Comment: I'd really like to hear a good answer to this as well. Used the `eps` terminal for the graphics for my bachelor report, then opened them with Preview on OS X, converted to .pdf, then inserted these into a LaTeX document. Oh, good times...

Answer (score 0):

I use the postscript output, and directly convert the output to `PDF` on the fly. I also change some more things during this, including the default postscript colors (for two color plots, red and blue is better than red and green, since some people are red-green-blind, for example). Another obvious improvement is to run `pdfcrop` afterwards.

Anyway, the trick is to use the external command syntax for output.

I have a script that looks approximately like this: (actually it is now a python script, for the color substitution)

```
#!/bin/sh
epstopdf --filter --outfile "$1"
pdfcrop "$1" "$1"
```

and then in gnuplot I use:

```
set output "| /home/myself/.bin/gnuplot-to-pdf file.pdf"
```

I have however no idea how to combine this with org-babel-mode (nor an idea what that is). It could however work with essentially giving the default output file name `file.pdf` and also specifying this for org-babel-gnuplot?

Comment: thanks for the answer.  unfortunately, the integration into org-babel-gnuplot is my actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

These articles may help :

[Include EPS graphics in pdflatex](http://chi3x10.wordpress.com/2009/06/18/eps-and-pdflatex-no-more-converting-eps-to-pdf/)
[org-exp-blocks.el — pre-process blocks when exporting org files](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-exp-blocks.html)

<sub>(Not having heard from you, I transformed my comment into an answer.)</sub>

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: I don't have the environment for testing it.

Comment: So you suggest using org-exp-blocks instead of org-babel?

Comment: The above are approaches that worked for some people, but may or may not work for you. I can't help you further.